# Collections.swap() in java swap everything in the method

Tags: java, collections, swap

I am trying to write simple code which swaps elements in a Vector (there are other irrelevant lines in the method for other purposes so please ignore them). However when I call Collections.swap(clone1, 6,3) it changes "v" vector as well!! What did I do wrong??

The Method:

```
public static String DFS(Vector v){

            Vector clone1 = new Vector();
            clone1 = v;
            Vector clone2 = new Vector();
            clone2 = v;


            // In order to compare goal is reached or not I created a goal vector
            Vector solution = new Vector(9,0);
            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                    solution.addElement(i);


            if(v.isEmpty()){
                    return "Empty!!";
            }
            if(v.equals(solution)){
                    return "Solution!!!";
            }

            // In order to determine where the blank is
            int indexOfZero = 0;

            // Since this Depth-First Search, I am using stack as frontier
            Stack s = new Stack();


            indexOfZero = v.indexOf('0');

            if (indexOfZero == 6){
                            Collections.swap(clone1,6,3);
                            Collections.swap(clone2,6,7);
            }

            //for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            //      s.push(list.get(i));
            //      System.out.println("Stack in for loop");
            //}

            //Vector a = (Vector)s.pop();
            System.out.println("\nElements after DFS:");
                    System.out.println(v.toString());
                    System.out.print("THIS IS MY ClONE 1: ");
                    System.out.println(clone1.toString());
                    System.out.print("THIS IS MY ClONE 2: ");
                    System.out.println(clone2.toString());
            System.out.println();
            return "a";
    }
```

Comment: Why a `Vector` in 2014? Why non parameterized Collections in 2014?

Comment: I am trying to learn Java's features,thats it. @fge

Comment: What do you think `clone1 = v;` and `clone2 = v;` do?

Comment: @user2094920 where from? Your reference reading is seriously outdated

Comment: @fge is right, this is an outdated way of writing Java. You should use `List<Integer>` and `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `Vector`. (List for the variable and parameter declarations, ArrayList when instantiating one.)

Comment: `Stack` is questionable, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared your references `clone1` and `clone2` to refer to the same object as `v` (and discarded the `new Vector()`s that were just created).

Using the assignment operator `=` with an object doesn't clone the object; it just makes another reference to refer to the same object.

```
v ----> Vector object
         ^
clone1 --+
```

You can create copies of your `Vector` by saying

```
Vector clone1 = new Vector(v);
```

Visually...

```
v ----> Vector object

clone1 ----> Cloned Vector object
```